# Права корневого пользователя в программе на Java (MacOS)

Tags: macos, java

Доброго времени суток!

Проблема такова. Нужна программа, которая выключает компьютер. Ну что-то типа таймера.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown -h now");
```

Тут происходит вызов выключения компьютера. Но программа просто-напросто не выключает компьютер из-за отсутствия прав суперюзера. В терминале нужно вводить пароль суперпользователя. Но как это реализовать в программе, я не понимаю.
Я новичок, поэтому заранее прошу прощения у всех, но как можно программе, не запрашивая у пользователя никаких данных, подтверждений, предоставить право на выключение компьютера?
Заранее спасибо!

**Дополнение 1**

Нашёл, что из терминала выключить компьютер можно вот так вот:

```
echo -e "mypass\n" | sudo -S shutdown -h now
```

Из терминала всё прекрасно сработало. Однако в программе это почему-то нет.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo -e \"mypass\\n\" | sudo -S shutdown -h now");
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему по-прежнему ничего не происходит? И как это можно исправить?

**Дополнение 2**

Проблему удалось частично решить следующим образом:

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("bash","-c","echo -e \"mypass\\n\" | sudo -S shutdown -h now");
b.start();
```

Всё замечательно работает из самой программы, хоть и работаеат она для частного случая. Общего решения, без привязки к конкретному паролю и без запросов пароля у пользователя, найти так и не удалось.

**Дополнение 3**

Проблему удалось решить с помощью AppleScript. Данная команда в терминале выключает компьютер без ввода пароля:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to shut down'
```

То есть в коде программы это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
 String script = "tell application \"System Events\" to shut down";
 ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
 ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("AppleScript");
 engine.eval(script);
```

Всем большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Последнее не работает, потому что Вы используете перенаправление bash, а exec просто исполняет программу. Поэтому нужно запускать через баш непосредственно. Скорее всего где-то так:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("basg 'echo -e \"mypass\\n\" | sudo -S shutdown -h now'");
```

Но хранить пароль внутри программы как-то неправильно.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, я понимаю. Но пока это единственный вариант, который более менее подходит, от которого можно отталкиваться. 
Попробовал запустить Ваш вариант - опять же никакой реакции.

Answer (score 1):

Вчера только разбирался с exec().
При использовании pipe вот так просто exec() будет выдавать ошибку, потому что это часть shell, а не unix утилита.
Попробуйте так:

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c",
                "echo -e \"mypass\\n\" | sudo -S shutdown -h now"};
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

**UPD**

Посмотрите отладчиком или выводом, что у вас в стримах, которые в Process.

```
p.getInputStream()
p.getErrorStream()
```

Вот эти два стрима, там можно увидеть ошибку и результат, если они есть.

**UPDUPD**

ну нужно смотреть внутри, проще всего вывести данные из этого стрима.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String out = "";
while((out = reader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.prinltn(out);
}
```

и аналогично с p.getErrorStream()

Comment: Попробовал Ваш вариант. Опять же никакой реакции, к сожалению.

Comment: @harooln, обновил.

Comment: @iksuy, прошу прощения, может, я просто что-то делаю не так. Вот что в отладчике: http://s019.radikal.ru/i633/1411/18/29f6b644c29e.png

Comment: @harooln, обновил